# Lapply slows with increasing loops

Tags: r

**Introduction**

I've been writing a program that processes some Raw data and then passes it through several statistical processes. All in all it uses several instances of "lapply".

**For example**: in one part of the script I use a function known as Maxstat (note the function only takes data either as data.frame or data.table - will not accept a matrix).

**

- **REPRODUCIBLE SAMPLE below - just copy all sample data, and two parts of the code**

**

**Sample data:**

The first two columns are neccesary. This is the large data sample seen below --> please read on after the sample

```
Genedata <- structure(list(time = c(120, 120, 28.96, 119.21, 59.53, 68.81, 
82.29, 110.82, 65.88, 84.13, 16.47, 89.75, 76.07, 67.82, 52.24, 
64.1, 55.13, 57.79, 50.1, 43.79, 30.27, 3.64, 36.59, 20.02, 118.58, 
55.33, 120, 120, 120, 106.94, 11.7, 28.79, 26.82, 52.5, 24.03, 
88.99, 102.44, 33.73, 85.28, 26.53, 37.31, 86.43, 55.92, 70.65, 
76.04, 79.13, 83.99, 80.25, 40.6, 95.37, 31.06, 37.31, 22.02, 
63.25, 34.09, 52.14, 66.04, 59.96, 47.86, 58.45, 45.99, 60.42, 
37.67, 15.71, 39.25, 49.87, 25.24, 44.97, 35.9, 26.66, 36.78, 
41.52, 22.22, 33.2, 39.68, 25.61, 83.99, 15.05, 8.38, 18.18, 
27.15, 24.26, 105.17, 11.76, 70.45, 95.07, 112.33, 27.51, 45.92, 
54.04, 103.98, 6.11, 99.51, 20.44, 76.6, 10.02, 41.45, 96.26, 
85.61, 78.87, 22.25, 74.53, 59.07, 47.8, 5.68, 79.39, 74.07, 
50.76, 67.82, 70.84, 50.59, 34.58, 38.72, 54.9, 67.92, 58.45, 
59.34, 54.54, 19.03, 26.26, 52.86, 32.05, 55.95, 56.67, 50.43, 
4.24, 49.11, 49.57, 50.49, 63.05, 49.24, 0.92, 31.36, 40.3, 116.64, 
31.92, 19.98, 24.62, 18.54, 120, 17.62, 5.32, 2.36, 5.72, 15.28, 
95.07, 4.96, 28.89, 3.25, 0.92, 18.77, 57.73, 14.39, 5.12, 4.99, 
33.17, 50.53, 5.72, 8.02, 34.02, 1.44, 36.95, 60.75, 37.44, 23.07, 
19.85, 31.85, 8.61, 42.27, 15.25, 14.56, 9.96, 8.94, 32.67, 2.07, 
22.78, 22.35), cens = c(0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("time", "cens"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-177L))
```

To generate a larger set -> **First define the sample above as Genedata**

then the additional code (to change variable/column length, just change 1000 to 5000 or 50000 etc.

```
    data <- replicate(1000, abs(rnorm(177)))
    Genedata <- data.frame(Genedata, data)
library(data.table)
    Genedata2 <- data.table(Genedata)
```

Then to calculate

```
    #Calculating Maxstat
    library(maxstat)
    maxstat.genes <- as.list( names(Genedata) )[-c(1:3)] #generate a list of column numbers
system.time(maxstat.estimate <-lapply( maxstat.genes, function (x)
{maxstat.test(Surv(time, cens) ~ get (x), data=Genedata2, smethod="LogRank",
pmethod="Lau94")}))
```

I originally planned on using the for statement, as i'm familiar with it having a background in python. However, research has told me that using apply should be faster.

I also originally used data.frame, but switched to data.table as someone suggested this should be better for performance.

However, it seems there is still a significant problem with processing large datasets. Below is an explanation of why.

**Running 25 variables**

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.00    0.05
```

**Running 1000 variables**

```
  user  system elapsed 
   6.54    0.00    6.57
```

**Running 5000 variables**

```
  user  system elapsed 
 132.89    0.00  133.02
```

As you can see, the processing speed is not linear but rather begins to fall off at a staggering rate. Given that the dataset is 43000 variables long, I can only guess that it would take on the order of hours. Interestingly, if i manually divided the tables into small sets, and ran them individually, it would be faster.

I think it has something to do with copying increasingly larger data, but I' not sure how this could be fixed. I already tried the data.table and lapply. Any suggestions?

**Update 1:**
Added sample data. Note to reproduce a larger dataset. You can copy columns 4 onwards and paste. Rows can also be copied down. Should work as far as i know.

**Update 2: Rprof on 1000 variables**

```
> Rprof(NULL)
> summaryRprof()
$by.self
                        self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
terms.formula                0.50    15.82       0.50     15.82
eval                         0.34    10.76       1.92     60.76
Surv                         0.12     3.80       0.20      6.33
.deparseOpts                 0.12     3.80       0.18      5.70
deparse                      0.08     2.53       0.32     10.13
na.omit.data.frame           0.08     2.53       0.30      9.49
lapply                       0.06     1.90       3.16    100.00
maxstat.test                 0.06     1.90       3.16    100.00
maxstat.test.data.frame      0.06     1.90       3.10     98.10
model.frame.default          0.06     1.90       1.68     53.16
cmaxstat                     0.06     1.90       0.38     12.03
match.arg                    0.06     1.90       0.30      9.49
ifelse                       0.06     1.90       0.06      1.90
is.matrix                    0.06     1.90       0.06      1.90
length                       0.06     1.90       0.06      1.90
match                        0.06     1.90       0.06      1.90
pmatch                       0.06     1.90       0.06      1.90
FUN                          0.04     1.27       3.16    100.00
maxstat                      0.04     1.27       0.90     28.48
terms                        0.04     1.27       0.62     19.62
[.data.frame                 0.04     1.27       0.20      6.33
order                        0.04     1.27       0.08      2.53
[.formula                    0.04     1.27       0.06      1.90
[.Surv                       0.04     1.27       0.06      1.90
attr.all.equal               0.04     1.27       0.06      1.90
makepredictcall              0.04     1.27       0.06      1.90
unique                       0.04     1.27       0.06      1.90
unlist                       0.04     1.27       0.06      1.90
<Anonymous>                  0.04     1.27       0.04      1.27
is.data.frame                0.04     1.27       0.04      1.27
names                        0.04     1.27       0.04      1.27
NextMethod                   0.04     1.27       0.04      1.27
sum                          0.04     1.27       0.04      1.27
model.frame                  0.02     0.63       1.70     53.80
na.omit                      0.02     0.63       0.32     10.13
[                            0.02     0.63       0.30      9.49
cscores                      0.02     0.63       0.28      8.86
cscores.Surv                 0.02     0.63       0.26      8.23
all.equal                    0.02     0.63       0.14      4.43
all.equal.numeric            0.02     0.63       0.12      3.80
paste                        0.02     0.63       0.12      3.80
[[                           0.02     0.63       0.08      2.53
sort                         0.02     0.63       0.08      2.53
[[.data.frame                0.02     0.63       0.06      1.90
sort.int                     0.02     0.63       0.06      1.90
as.list                      0.02     0.63       0.04      1.27
as.vector                    0.02     0.63       0.04      1.27
get                          0.02     0.63       0.04      1.27
-                            0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
$<-                          0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
/                            0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
anyDuplicated                0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
as.environment               0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
as.list.data.frame           0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
attr                         0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
attr<-                       0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
c                            0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
cbind                        0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
data.class                   0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
is.array                     0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
makepredictcall.default      0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
mode                         0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
pLausen94                    0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63
sys.function                 0.02     0.63       0.02      0.63

$by.total
                        total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
lapply                        3.16    100.00      0.06     1.90
maxstat.test                  3.16    100.00      0.06     1.90
FUN                           3.16    100.00      0.04     1.27
maxstat.test.data.frame       3.10     98.10      0.06     1.90
eval                          1.92     60.76      0.34    10.76
model.frame                   1.70     53.80      0.02     0.63
model.frame.default           1.68     53.16      0.06     1.90
maxstat                       0.90     28.48      0.04     1.27
do.call                       0.90     28.48      0.00     0.00
terms                         0.62     19.62      0.04     1.27
terms.formula                 0.50     15.82      0.50    15.82
cmaxstat                      0.38     12.03      0.06     1.90
sapply                        0.34     10.76      0.00     0.00
deparse                       0.32     10.13      0.08     2.53
na.omit                       0.32     10.13      0.02     0.63
na.omit.data.frame            0.30      9.49      0.08     2.53
match.arg                     0.30      9.49      0.06     1.90
[                             0.30      9.49      0.02     0.63
cscores                       0.28      8.86      0.02     0.63
cscores.Surv                  0.26      8.23      0.02     0.63
Surv                          0.20      6.33      0.12     3.80
[.data.frame                  0.20      6.33      0.04     1.27
.deparseOpts                  0.18      5.70      0.12     3.80
all.equal                     0.14      4.43      0.02     0.63
all.equal.numeric             0.12      3.80      0.02     0.63
paste                         0.12      3.80      0.02     0.63
order                         0.08      2.53      0.04     1.27
[[                            0.08      2.53      0.02     0.63
sort                          0.08      2.53      0.02     0.63
ifelse                        0.06      1.90      0.06     1.90
is.matrix                     0.06      1.90      0.06     1.90
length                        0.06      1.90      0.06     1.90
match                         0.06      1.90      0.06     1.90
pmatch                        0.06      1.90      0.06     1.90
[.formula                     0.06      1.90      0.04     1.27
[.Surv                        0.06      1.90      0.04     1.27
attr.all.equal                0.06      1.90      0.04     1.27
makepredictcall               0.06      1.90      0.04     1.27
unique                        0.06      1.90      0.04     1.27
unlist                        0.06      1.90      0.04     1.27
[[.data.frame                 0.06      1.90      0.02     0.63
sort.int                      0.06      1.90      0.02     0.63
%in%                          0.06      1.90      0.00     0.00
simplify2array                0.06      1.90      0.00     0.00
sort.default                  0.06      1.90      0.00     0.00
<Anonymous>                   0.04      1.27      0.04     1.27
is.data.frame                 0.04      1.27      0.04     1.27
names                         0.04      1.27      0.04     1.27
NextMethod                    0.04      1.27      0.04     1.27
sum                           0.04      1.27      0.04     1.27
as.list                       0.04      1.27      0.02     0.63
as.vector                     0.04      1.27      0.02     0.63
get                           0.04      1.27      0.02     0.63
-                             0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
$<-                           0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
/                             0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
anyDuplicated                 0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
as.environment                0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
as.list.data.frame            0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
attr                          0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
attr<-                        0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
c                             0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
cbind                         0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
data.class                    0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
is.array                      0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
makepredictcall.default       0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
mode                          0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
pLausen94                     0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
sys.function                  0.02      0.63      0.02     0.63
formals                       0.02      0.63      0.00     0.00
is.na                         0.02      0.63      0.00     0.00
is.na.Surv                    0.02      0.63      0.00     0.00
rowSums                       0.02      0.63      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 3.16
```

**Update 3 - Rprof on 5000 variables - as you can see its not linear increase**

```
> Rprof(NULL)
> summaryRprof()
$by.self
                        self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
eval                        11.28    32.83      23.40     68.10
terms.formula               11.00    32.01      11.08     32.25
model.frame.default          0.68     1.98      22.38     65.13
deparse                      0.68     1.98       1.70      4.95
cmaxstat                     0.46     1.34       2.38      6.93
.deparseOpts                 0.44     1.28       0.74      2.15
na.omit.data.frame           0.40     1.16       1.74      5.06
[.data.frame                 0.36     1.05       1.06      3.08
maxstat.test.data.frame      0.32     0.93      34.16     99.42
pmatch                       0.32     0.93       0.34      0.99
match                        0.28     0.81       0.60      1.75
NextMethod                   0.28     0.81       0.28      0.81
na.omit                      0.26     0.76       2.00      5.82
Surv                         0.26     0.76       0.54      1.57
get                          0.26     0.76       0.28      0.81
unique                       0.24     0.70       0.46      1.34
makepredictcall              0.24     0.70       0.36      1.05
order                        0.24     0.70       0.34      0.99
match.arg                    0.22     0.64       1.26      3.67
[.Surv                       0.22     0.64       0.40      1.16
lapply                       0.20     0.58      34.36    100.00
paste                        0.20     0.58       0.90      2.62
maxstat                      0.18     0.52       4.50     13.10
[                            0.18     0.52       1.54      4.48
cscores                      0.18     0.52       1.26      3.67
$<-                          0.18     0.52       0.18      0.52
terms                        0.16     0.47      11.46     33.35
sort.int                     0.16     0.47       0.46      1.34
cbind                        0.16     0.47       0.16      0.47
is.matrix                    0.16     0.47       0.16      0.47
length                       0.16     0.47       0.16      0.47
[[.data.frame                0.14     0.41       0.34      0.99
FUN                          0.12     0.35      34.26     99.71
all.equal.numeric            0.12     0.35       0.24      0.70
c                            0.12     0.35       0.12      0.35
ifelse                       0.12     0.35       0.12      0.35
is.data.frame                0.12     0.35       0.12      0.35
makepredictcall.default      0.12     0.35       0.12      0.35
names                        0.12     0.35       0.12      0.35
cscores.Surv                 0.10     0.29       1.08      3.14
%in%                         0.10     0.29       0.70      2.04
all.equal                    0.10     0.29       0.40      1.16
mode                         0.10     0.29       0.34      0.99
unlist                       0.10     0.29       0.20      0.58
unique.default               0.10     0.29       0.16      0.47
as.list                      0.10     0.29       0.10      0.29
dim                          0.10     0.29       0.10      0.29
is.factor                    0.10     0.29       0.10      0.29
parent.frame                 0.10     0.29       0.10      0.29
model.frame                  0.08     0.23      22.46     65.37
is.na                        0.08     0.23       0.18      0.52
duplicated                   0.08     0.23       0.12      0.35
maxstat.test                 0.06     0.17      34.22     99.59
sapply                       0.06     0.17       1.72      5.01
sort                         0.06     0.17       0.52      1.51
pLausen94                    0.06     0.17       0.22      0.64
anyDuplicated                0.06     0.17       0.10      0.29
which                        0.06     0.17       0.10      0.29
ncol                         0.06     0.17       0.08      0.23
rowSums                      0.06     0.17       0.08      0.23
*                            0.06     0.17       0.06      0.17
/                            0.06     0.17       0.06      0.17
environment                  0.06     0.17       0.06      0.17
is.ordered                   0.06     0.17       0.06      0.17
list                         0.06     0.17       0.06      0.17
do.call                      0.04     0.12       4.56     13.27
[[                           0.04     0.12       0.38      1.11
attr.all.equal               0.04     0.12       0.10      0.29
formals                      0.04     0.12       0.08      0.23
!                            0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
.Call                        0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
<Anonymous>                  0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
anyDuplicated.default        0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
duplicated.default           0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
floor                        0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
is.array                     0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
match.fun                    0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
options                      0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
pnorm                        0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
seq.default                  0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
sys.call                     0.04     0.12       0.04      0.12
simplify2array               0.02     0.06       0.52      1.51
[.formula                    0.02     0.06       0.14      0.41
is.na.Surv                   0.02     0.06       0.10      0.29
sys.function                 0.02     0.06       0.04      0.12
&                            0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
.row_names_info              0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
^                            0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
<                            0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
<=                           0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
==                           0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
as.environment               0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
attr<-                       0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
baseenv                      0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
data.class                   0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
is.numeric                   0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
sqrt                         0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
sum                          0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06
sys.parent                   0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06

$by.total
                        total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
lapply                       34.36    100.00      0.20     0.58
FUN                          34.26     99.71      0.12     0.35
maxstat.test                 34.22     99.59      0.06     0.17
maxstat.test.data.frame      34.16     99.42      0.32     0.93
eval                         23.40     68.10     11.28    32.83
model.frame                  22.46     65.37      0.08     0.23
model.frame.default          22.38     65.13      0.68     1.98
terms                        11.46     33.35      0.16     0.47
terms.formula                11.08     32.25     11.00    32.01
do.call                       4.56     13.27      0.04     0.12
maxstat                       4.50     13.10      0.18     0.52
cmaxstat                      2.38      6.93      0.46     1.34
na.omit                       2.00      5.82      0.26     0.76
na.omit.data.frame            1.74      5.06      0.40     1.16
sapply                        1.72      5.01      0.06     0.17
deparse                       1.70      4.95      0.68     1.98
[                             1.54      4.48      0.18     0.52
match.arg                     1.26      3.67      0.22     0.64
cscores                       1.26      3.67      0.18     0.52
cscores.Surv                  1.08      3.14      0.10     0.29
[.data.frame                  1.06      3.08      0.36     1.05
paste                         0.90      2.62      0.20     0.58
.deparseOpts                  0.74      2.15      0.44     1.28
%in%                          0.70      2.04      0.10     0.29
match                         0.60      1.75      0.28     0.81
Surv                          0.54      1.57      0.26     0.76
sort                          0.52      1.51      0.06     0.17
simplify2array                0.52      1.51      0.02     0.06
unique                        0.46      1.34      0.24     0.70
sort.int                      0.46      1.34      0.16     0.47
sort.default                  0.46      1.34      0.00     0.00
[.Surv                        0.40      1.16      0.22     0.64
all.equal                     0.40      1.16      0.10     0.29
[[                            0.38      1.11      0.04     0.12
makepredictcall               0.36      1.05      0.24     0.70
pmatch                        0.34      0.99      0.32     0.93
order                         0.34      0.99      0.24     0.70
[[.data.frame                 0.34      0.99      0.14     0.41
mode                          0.34      0.99      0.10     0.29
NextMethod                    0.28      0.81      0.28     0.81
get                           0.28      0.81      0.26     0.76
all.equal.numeric             0.24      0.70      0.12     0.35
pLausen94                     0.22      0.64      0.06     0.17
unlist                        0.20      0.58      0.10     0.29
$<-                           0.18      0.52      0.18     0.52
is.na                         0.18      0.52      0.08     0.23
cbind                         0.16      0.47      0.16     0.47
is.matrix                     0.16      0.47      0.16     0.47
length                        0.16      0.47      0.16     0.47
unique.default                0.16      0.47      0.10     0.29
[.formula                     0.14      0.41      0.02     0.06
c                             0.12      0.35      0.12     0.35
ifelse                        0.12      0.35      0.12     0.35
is.data.frame                 0.12      0.35      0.12     0.35
makepredictcall.default       0.12      0.35      0.12     0.35
names                         0.12      0.35      0.12     0.35
duplicated                    0.12      0.35      0.08     0.23
as.list                       0.10      0.29      0.10     0.29
dim                           0.10      0.29      0.10     0.29
is.factor                     0.10      0.29      0.10     0.29
parent.frame                  0.10      0.29      0.10     0.29
anyDuplicated                 0.10      0.29      0.06     0.17
which                         0.10      0.29      0.06     0.17
attr.all.equal                0.10      0.29      0.04     0.12
is.na.Surv                    0.10      0.29      0.02     0.06
ncol                          0.08      0.23      0.06     0.17
rowSums                       0.08      0.23      0.06     0.17
formals                       0.08      0.23      0.04     0.12
as.vector                     0.08      0.23      0.00     0.00
*                             0.06      0.17      0.06     0.17
/                             0.06      0.17      0.06     0.17
environment                   0.06      0.17      0.06     0.17
is.ordered                    0.06      0.17      0.06     0.17
list                          0.06      0.17      0.06     0.17
nrow                          0.06      0.17      0.00     0.00
!                             0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
.Call                         0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
<Anonymous>                   0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
anyDuplicated.default         0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
duplicated.default            0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
floor                         0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
is.array                      0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
match.fun                     0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
options                       0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
pnorm                         0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
seq.default                   0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
sys.call                      0.04      0.12      0.04     0.12
sys.function                  0.04      0.12      0.02     0.06
getOption                     0.04      0.12      0.00     0.00
irank                         0.04      0.12      0.00     0.00
seq                           0.04      0.12      0.00     0.00
&                             0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
.row_names_info               0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
^                             0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
<                             0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
<=                            0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
==                            0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
as.environment                0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
attr<-                        0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
baseenv                       0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
data.class                    0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
is.numeric                    0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
sqrt                          0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
sum                           0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
sys.parent                    0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06
match.call                    0.02      0.06      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 34.36
```

Comment: We need a [**reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to run your function and find out what's going on. As of now, I can only suggest you use `profiling` to find out which part does your code spend most of the time... `?Rprof`.

Comment: Have added sample data. Hope this helps.

Comment: why are there some values missing in the 3rd column?

Comment: @PyPerUser your sample data is not big enough to re-create the problem.  please re-read Arun's link and pay attention to the part that shows how to create _fake data_.  people on SO would love to help, but you should make our side of things as easy as you can.  :)

Comment: Hopefully this will help; reformatted data for R.

Comment: Wrap your `lapply` line with `Rprof()` in the front and `Rprof(NULL)` and `summaryRprof()` after the line, and copy/paste all these 4 lines (`Rprof()`, `lapply(...)`, `Rprof(NULL)`, `summaryRprof()`) and run it and paste the output here...

Comment: OK. sorry for the delay. There is a reproducible sample now. BUt I did run the RProf as well. Im not sure what you mean by paste all 4 lines, but I did do the RProf before and after the Lapply. Output is very long...

Comment: Need to go to sleep right now. But there is reproducible example. I've posted all I can. Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: @PyPerUser By "4 lines", read "4 statements". I.e. run `Rprof()`, then your `lapply()` code, then run `Rprof(NULL)`, then run `summaryRprof()`. You can't write lines in comments easily, hence Arun separated the statements with commas.

Comment: +1 to @Arun for `RProf` -- was unaware of it

Comment: Yep; the above two examples in the question were done this way.

Comment: Haven't done any testing, but sometimes in cases like this it's a memory issue.  If that's the case, a `for` loop could possibly be faster and have linear performance.

Comment: Memory issue how? While running lapply, system memory usage didn't go past 30%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a full answer to why the times for lapply are not linear, but notice that you are using lapply as a glorified loop by applying over a list of variable names (and then using these names to index the actual values) rather than applying over a list of values. I'm not sure how to solve this using lapply, but I can offer an alternative that  is (roughly) a liner function of the number of variables.

Start by creating the example data:

```
Genedata <- structure(list(time = c(120, 120, 28.96, 119.21, 59.53, 68.81, 
82.29, 110.82, 65.88, 84.13, 16.47, 89.75, 76.07, 67.82, 52.24, 
64.1, 55.13, 57.79, 50.1, 43.79, 30.27, 3.64, 36.59, 20.02, 118.58, 
55.33, 120, 120, 120, 106.94, 11.7, 28.79, 26.82, 52.5, 24.03, 
88.99, 102.44, 33.73, 85.28, 26.53, 37.31, 86.43, 55.92, 70.65, 
76.04, 79.13, 83.99, 80.25, 40.6, 95.37, 31.06, 37.31, 22.02, 
63.25, 34.09, 52.14, 66.04, 59.96, 47.86, 58.45, 45.99, 60.42, 
37.67, 15.71, 39.25, 49.87, 25.24, 44.97, 35.9, 26.66, 36.78, 
41.52, 22.22, 33.2, 39.68, 25.61, 83.99, 15.05, 8.38, 18.18, 
27.15, 24.26, 105.17, 11.76, 70.45, 95.07, 112.33, 27.51, 45.92, 
54.04, 103.98, 6.11, 99.51, 20.44, 76.6, 10.02, 41.45, 96.26, 
85.61, 78.87, 22.25, 74.53, 59.07, 47.8, 5.68, 79.39, 74.07, 
50.76, 67.82, 70.84, 50.59, 34.58, 38.72, 54.9, 67.92, 58.45, 
59.34, 54.54, 19.03, 26.26, 52.86, 32.05, 55.95, 56.67, 50.43, 
4.24, 49.11, 49.57, 50.49, 63.05, 49.24, 0.92, 31.36, 40.3, 116.64, 
31.92, 19.98, 24.62, 18.54, 120, 17.62, 5.32, 2.36, 5.72, 15.28, 
95.07, 4.96, 28.89, 3.25, 0.92, 18.77, 57.73, 14.39, 5.12, 4.99, 
33.17, 50.53, 5.72, 8.02, 34.02, 1.44, 36.95, 60.75, 37.44, 23.07, 
19.85, 31.85, 8.61, 42.27, 15.25, 14.56, 9.96, 8.94, 32.67, 2.07, 
22.78, 22.35), cens = c(0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("time", "cens"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-177L))

data <- replicate(10000, abs(rnorm(177)))
Genedata <- data.frame(Genedata, data)
```

My approach is the reshape the data using the `melt` function in the reshape2 package, then use `dlply` from the plyr package to run the model on each subset.

```
ibrary(maxstat)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)

system.time({
  dat.m <- melt(Genedata, id.vars=1:3)
  maxstat.estimate <- dlply(dat.m, .(variable), function(DF) {
  maxstat.test(Surv(time, cens) ~ value, smethod="LogRank", pmethod="Lau94", data=DF)})})
```

Some timings from this approach are as follows:

```
## 1000 variables
##    user  system elapsed 
##  11.613   0.090  11.780 

## 2000 variables
##   user  system elapsed
## 23.847   0.060  24.043

## 3000 variables
##    user  system elapsed 
##  35.316   0.093  35.905

## 10000 variables
##    user  system elapsed 
## 120.654   0.594 122.140
```

showing that system time is roughly a linear function of the number of variables.

The full 43000 variables takes just over 10 minutes, just enough time for a cup of coffee:

```
## 43000
##    user  system elapsed 
## 612.587   3.134 630.464
```

Comment: Ok problem solved :) cheers. It works well, surprising considering lapply is usually suggested for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any non-linear behaviour on my machine:

```
library(maxstat)
genes <- names(Genedata)[-(1:3)]

time_it <- function(f, vars = c(25, 100, 500, 999)) {
  names(vars) <- vars
  sapply(vars, function(x) system.time(lapply(genes[1:x], f))[3]) / vars
}

fit_model <- function(var) {
  maxstat.test(Surv(time, cens) ~ get(var), data = Genedata, 
    smethod = "LogRank", pmethod = "Lau94")
}
time_it(fit_model)
#  25.elapsed 100.elapsed 500.elapsed 999.elapsed 
#    1.800000    1.790000    1.812000    1.857858
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned switching to `data.table`, but it doesn't appear like you took full advantage of it.  The key here is to reshape the table to "long" format, and then use `data.table` to group `by` your variable.  Picking up from your example `Genedata`...

```
library(data.table)
library(maxstat)
system.time({

## Convert to a "long" data.table format: 
Genedata2 <- data.table(time=rep(Genedata[[1]],ncol(Genedata)-2),
                        cens=rep(Genedata[[2]],ncol(Genedata)-2),
                        variable=rep(1:(ncol(Genedata)-2), each=nrow(Genedata)),
                        value=as.vector(as.matrix(Genedata[3:ncol(Genedata)])))

## Calculate the maxstat.test by each variable:
maxstat.estimate2 <- Genedata2[,list(ans=list(maxstat.test(Surv(time, cens) ~ value,
                     data=.SD, smethod="LogRank", pmethod="Lau94"))), by="variable"]
})


## 1,000 variables:
##  user  system elapsed 
##  2.01    0.00    2.01

## 5,000 variables:
##  user  system elapsed 
## 12.17    0.00   12.17

## 10,000 variables:
##  user  system elapsed 
## 21.19    0.07   21.25

## 43,000 variables:
##  user  system elapsed 
## 96.91    0.21   97.22
```

If you are doing other calculations on the same data, you can just add them as new columns in the line of code that creates the maxstat.estimate2 table (`list(ans=..., calc2=..., calc3=..., etc.)`).